# Вывод первых значений в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть следующая база данных, где нужно выбрать самую позднюю дату.

[Залил данные](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=gQlcdyyKLB)

Стоит задание : вывести самую позднюю дату рождения

Делаю следующий код:

```
select ID,Date_Birth  from mytable order by Date_Birth DESC 
limit 1
```

Выводит одну запись, но в базе данных две самых поздних даты с разными ID.
Как построить код, чтобы он выводил все поздние даты (независимо от того , будет ли их 2,3,4 и тд)

Код написан в mysql v5.7

Comment: добавьте `GROUP BY id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все довольно просто:

```
select ID,Date_Birth
from mytable
where Date_Birth = (select max(Date_Birth) from mytable)
```